# Casting and checking values for multiple types

Tags: swift

From the code below:

```
import Foundation

func checkStatus(statusObj: AnyObject) -> String {
    if let status = statusObj as? String where status.lowercaseString == "ok" {
        return "success"
    } else if let status = statusObj as? Int where status >= 200 && status < 300 {
        return "success"
    } else {
        return "failed"
    }
}

print(checkStatus("ok"))
print(checkStatus(200))
print(checkStatus("error"))
print(checkStatus(500))
```

Is there a way to combine the two success conditions into one single statement?

Comment: That should be the way you do it. Combining may introduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing it this way, using switch and fallthrough:

```
func checkStatus(statusObj: AnyObject) -> String {
    switch statusObj {
    case let status as Int where 200..<300 ~= status:
        fallthrough
    case "ok" as String:
        return "success"
    default:
        return "failed"
    }
}
```

I had to reverse the tests as fallthrough won't work over a case with let.

Comment: the returning value has two possible states, doesn't it? why not simply return Bool from your function?

Comment: That makes sense. I'll do that.